# Return a new number that is unlike the current numbers inside the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have this problem about arrays that I can't seem to solve. What I'm trying to do is to **return numbers** that are not inside the array. **Return** can only be done **if the new value is not inside the array**, else it's going to **increment the value** (to make sure that **there is no space**).

My code goes like:

```
function create_number(number) {
  var array = [1,2,3,6,7,8,9];
  for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    if (array[i] == number) {
      return number;
    } else {
      // create a new number that is not inside the array, and return it.
    }
    // If not just do the loop again. 
    // If the loop is over, then just create a valid number 
    // that is not found inside the array.
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the conditions? `100` is a valid number?

Comment: What would be the result for the provided code? `4`? Then `5`, then `10`?

Comment: Yes, the conditions include 100, but trying to avoid number spaces. This means that 4, 5, and 10 could be valid.

Comment: And then you push that number into the array? Does it have to be sorted? We need more info...

Comment: Yes, it will eventually be pushed, but not on this function. No, it does not need to be sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var array = [1,2,3,6,7,8,9];
var number = 0;
while (true) {
    if (array.indexOf(++number) == -1) {
        array.push(number);
        return number;
    }
}
```

but you need to persist `array` somewhere

PS: [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) shim for ancient browsers (credits to @Lochemage)

PPS: the solution above is `O(N^2)`, just for fun here is `O(N)` one (it requires the `array` to be sorted initially):

```
var array = [1,2,3,6,7,8,9];
var number = 1;
while (true) {
    if (array[number - 1] != number) {
        array.splice(number - 1, 0, number);
        return number;
    }
    ++number;
}
```

Comment: Note: indexOf is not supported on all browsers.  You can easily implement it yourself though.